# How to keep showing LINQ results when 'Next' button pressed?

Tags: c#, linq, list, button

I have a LINQ query attached to a 'Next' button. I want to display the results in some fields inside a form. As of right now I can only show one element when I press the 'Next' button, when I press the 'Next' button one more time nothing happens

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
        int count = 1;

        var elements =
            from element in list
            select element;

        if(count <= elements.Count())
        {
            FName.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).fName;
            LName.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).lName;
            Phone.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).Phone;
            Gpa.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).Gpa.ToString();

            count++;
        }
    }
```

Basically, every time I press the 'Next' button I want to keep displaying the elements in the list until it reaches the end of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are re-initialising your count to 1 every time Next is pressed. Move the variable declaration to a private instance field:

```
class MyApp {
    // ...
    private int count = 0;
}
```

You also need to change `count` to be zero-indexed, since `ElementAt` is zero-indexed. Simply initialise `count` to 0, and change your condition to read `if (count < elements.Count())`.

Note that in your code you can use the LINQ extension methods on `list` directly, bypassing the need to create `elements`.

Comment: btw I have count initialized as 1 cause I have another button that displays the first element (0 index) in the list, then enables the 'Next' button

Comment: @JGeZau: OK then, but your condition should still be `<` not `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int count = 1;    
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPrevious.Enabled = true;

        var elements =
            from element in list
            select element;

        if(count <= elements.Count())
        {
            FName.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).fName;
            LName.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).lName;
            Phone.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).Phone;
            Gpa.Text = elements.ElementAt(count).Gpa.ToString();

            count++;
        }
    }
```